# AngularJS $animate not adding CSS class in directive

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I'm trying to add some animations to an site with angularJS. It's the first time I'm using angular and I couldn't find out where the problem is.

**Idea**

When I'm hovering over an image, it should be highlighted in some way.

**Approach**

a) Writing my own directive:

```
app.directive('highlighting', ['$animate', function($animate) {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.on('mouseenter', function() {
            $animate.removeClass(element, 'mouseleave');
            $animate.addClass(element, 'mouseenter');

            console.log("enter"); //this works
        });
        element.on('mouseleave', function() {
            $animate.removeClass(element, 'mouseenter');
            $animate.addClass(element, 'mouseleave');

            console.log("leave"); //yup, also firing 
        });
    };
}]);
```

b) adding an CSS class:

```
.home-img {
opacity: 0;
}

.home-img.mouseover {
-webkit-animation: 0.5s fade-in;
-moz-animation: 0.5s fade-in;
-o-animation: 0.5s fade-in;
animation: 0.5s fade-in;
z-index: 100;
}

.home-img.mouseleave {
-webkit-animation: 0.5s fade-out;
-moz-animation: 0.5s fade-out;
-o-animation: 0.5s fade-out;    
animation: 0.5s fade-out;
z-index:99;
}

@keyframes fade-in {
from { opacity: 0; }
to { opacity: 1; }
}
@-moz-keyframes fade-in {
from { opacity: 0; }
to { opacity: 1; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fade-in {
from { opacity: 0; }
to { opacity: 1; }
}
@keyframes fade-out {
from { opacity: 1; }
to { opacity: 0; }
}
@-moz-keyframes fade-out {
from { opacity: 1; }
to { opacity: 0; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fade-out {
from { opacity: 1; }
to { opacity: 0; }
}
```

c) finally. bring things together on html:

```
<img src="my.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block no-margin home-img" ng-class="" id="img_how" highlighting>
```

Comment: it seems you can use css:hover to achieve what you're trying to do?

Comment: Yeah, I know, but it is more a start of tests for using angular animations.